# Mocking a Predicate in Java using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, predicate, spy

I have a Predicate which checks for a row existence in Database.I am not sure if this is a good use of predicate but it made my code clean and concise.But when I am Tesing this code I am not able to mock the DAO class and not sure why is the case.

```
public class validator{

public Predicate<String> doesRowExists = fileName -> makeDao().isRowReturned(RowId);

  public AlertFileDAO makeDataDao(){
        return new DataDao();
    }

  public boolean validate(String RowId){
        return doesRowExists.test(rowId)
    }

}

//Test

public class ValidatorTest{

@setup
void beforeAll(){
  mockValidator = spy(new Validator());
  doReturn(mockDataDao)
                .when(mockValidator)
                .makeDataDao();
}

@Test
test_whenRowExists(){
new Validator.validate("1-abc-34");
}
```

When Im triggering the test it is hitting the actual DB and not using the mocked DAO class.Im not sure what exactly I am missing here.Please suggest.

Comment: Pls take time to check If the code you post makes sense. Here: `new Validator.validate` does not compile. Youbare using makeDao in your predicate but the only shown method is called makeDataDao

Comment: Im sorry that the code doesn't compile but I think I solved the problem by wrapping the predicate inside a method which is exactly what ADS had proposed.

Comment: Why don’t you simply inline the predicate and deliver the dao as constructor argument? This makes your api cleaner: method call vs getter for predicate and test on predicate you ended up with.

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you please provide code as an answer, it can help others who might end up here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don’t you simply inline the predicate and deliver the dao as constructor argument? This makes your api cleaner: method call vs getter for predicate and test on predicate you ended up with.

With your accepted answer, the user has to use the following:

```
validator.doesRowExist().test(rowId);
```

I believe the following would be easier to use:

```
validator.doesRowExist(rowId);
```

or even:

```
validator.validate(rowId);
```

Lets make a series of refactorings to achieve that:

**Step 1:**

You use your predicate to implement `validate` function. There are no other calls, nor passing to another functions (higher-order functions accepting a predicate are a typical use for them). Let's change the predicate to a method:

```
public class Validator {

    public DataDao makeDataDao(){
        return new DataDao();
    }

    public boolean validate(String rowId){
        return doesRowExist(rowId);
    }

    private boolean doesRowExist(String rowId) {
        return makeDataDao().isRowReturned(rowId);
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

Daos are typically singletons (one instance of them is enough). Depending on the frameworks you use, creating a Dao may be more costly than calling a method on it. Let's apply dependency injection principles (class receives it dependencies, not creates them):

```
public class Validator {

    private final DataDao dataDao;

    Validator(DataDao dataDao) {
        this.dataDao = dataDao;
    }

    public boolean validate(String rowId){
        return doesRowExist(rowId);
    }

    private boolean doesRowExist(String rowId) {
        return dataDao.isRowReturned(rowId);
    }
}
```

If you really need to create Dao each time, you can provide a fecory in the constructor.

**Result:**

Your class:

- has nicer api
- is likely more efficient
- is trivially testable:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ValidatorTest {

    @Mock
    DataDao mockDataDao;

    @InjectMocks
    Validator validator;

    @Test
    void whenValidateReturnsValueFromIsRowReturned(){
        var rowId = "1-abc-34";
        doReturn(false)
                .when(mockDataDao)
                .isRowReturned(rowId);
        assertEquals(false, validator.validate(rowId));
    }

}
```

Comment: Though ADS answer is quite valid for stubbing out fields in order to mock in general,I went ahead with this approach which might take longer to implement but a produces a rather neat extendable API.

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem as example of more common task: *how to stub a field*. In your case, you need to stub field `doesRowExists`.

The common task has common solution: **use getter instead**: `public Predicate<String> getDoesRowExists() { return doesRowExists;}` or, with common code style, `public Predicate<String> isRowExists() { return doesRowExists;}`

So, in your production code you call getter instead field: `return isRowExists().test(rowId)`
In your test code you just mock this getter: `when(isRowExists).thenReturn(true)`